# Azure Service Bus subscription filters not working

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I hope someone can shed some light on this as its wasted a day of my time already with no end in sight.

I am sending messages to a topic/subscription setup in Azure Service Bus and using the subject/label correlation filter to sort them in to subscriptions with a GUID that identifies a product.

This seemed to work perfectly in the past, but for the last 2 days messages sent to the proper topic were just disappearing - so I added a "default" subscription (1=1 filter) at the bottom of the filters list (just in case it processes them in order), and low and behold my missing messages started appearing there.

So here is the issue. Looking at the data in the azure service bus explorer I cannot see why the filters are not being applied. All the data is correct and the filters look correct... will post screen grabs below. Does anyone here see anything "off" on this that might indicate why the shown message is not being routed properly?

--Filter settings:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M45or.png)

Note: I also tried changing that to CorrelationID to no avail.

Here are the properties on the messages that will not go in to that subscription, but are instead being routed to the default subscription I created:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhnxi.png)

As you can see the GUIDs for Subject and Correlation ID are the same, and the same as is set in the filter. There are no spaces, extra or invisible characters, etc.

Now... lets throw some sticks in to the wheels eh? ... the only thing that changed between the time it was working to when it stopped working is that we added a Queue and started using that as well, in a different application, but in the same service bus. The way the process works, if it matters, is one application sends a message to the queue which is then consumed by another application, processed and then sent back to the topic/subscription that was noted in the original messages replyTo field (pipe delimited topic/queue GUIDs), and the subsequent return has that ReplyTo removed.

And because I know the question will be thought if not asked (haha), the reason we use both a queue and a topic is because we have multiple clients on one side each handled by their own apps, but only a single consumer on the other side... so a queue will work for the one, but we need to route messages to the right client/app (topic/subscription) on the other side.

Sorry if I gave too much or not enough detail... this is my first in depth attempt at coding with the azure service bus, so I might very well be missing something very simple.

TIA

Dave

I have tried changing the filter on the subscription to different fields than Subject - correlation ID, ReplyTo - but none worked.

Comment: When you add a catch-all filter and inspect the message, is subject/label value an upper case or lower case? Trying to rule out the case change in between queue and subscription use cases.

Comment: Both the same. I checked that as well. all upper case... and in fact its using the very same value passed on from the incoming message.

Comment: Just thought I would add this for clarity: 

D7A4437F-FDE9-48CB-BD72-622756C795C2  -- filter setting
D7A4437F-FDE9-48CB-BD72-622756C795C2  -- correlation id
D7A4437F-FDE9-48CB-BD72-622756C795C2  -- subject

Comment: To confirm, did you try it with another entity or namespace?

Comment: @SeanFeldman no, because in our use-case we need to run this under a single entity. The "workaround" I am using is to just create queues for each client+product and use queues instead of topic/sub ... it works, but it is not very elegant and makes for hard troubleshooting. I would like to resolve this if I can, but I can work around it if not.

Answer (score 0):

- The code demonstrates how to create a subscription with a correlation filter, send a message to a topic with matching correlation properties, and then receive and print the message from the subscription.
- This is the code reference [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples.md).

```
    const string connectionString = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString";
    const string topicName = "AzureServiceBusTopic";
    const string subscriptionName = "AzureServiceBusSubscription";

    try
    {
        // Create a Service Bus Administration Client object to manage topics and subscriptions
        var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);

        // Create a correlation filter with color set to Red and priority set to High
        var correlationFilter = new CorrelationRuleFilter
        {
            Subject = "red",
            CorrelationId = "high"
        };

        // Create a subscription with the correlation filter
        await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(
            new CreateSubscriptionOptions(topicName, subscriptionName),
            new CreateRuleOptions("HighPriorityRedOrders", correlationFilter));

        // Now, let's send a message to the topic with matching correlation properties
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        var sender = client.CreateSender(topicName);

        var message = new ServiceBusMessage("This is a high-priority message")
        {
            CorrelationId = "high",
            Subject = "red"
        };

        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");

        // Create a receiver for the subscription to receive the matching message
        var receiver = client.CreateReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName);

        // Receive the message from the subscription
        var receivedMessage = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

        if (receivedMessage != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {receivedMessage.Body.ToString()}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No messages received.");
        }

        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know all of this - and to be clear, it works - just not all the time. Some messages are being sent but not added to a subscription that their data says they should be dropped in to.

Comment: For issue Azure service bus dropping messages refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319327/azure-service-bus-dropping-messages)